# Create an ASP.NET Core 3 MVC from empty project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm starting a project from scratch to understand in depth the core features, and i'm failing to create an MVC application from the empty template. All i get is 404 even on the default route.

To start, I'm using the latest vs code, and created the empty project on the cli with:

```
dotnet new web
```

After project creation, i changed the Startup.cs to configure my routes.
I was reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure) article to see the changes made to the 3.0 version.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
...
       app.UseRouting();
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I created all the MVC folders, a HomeController with the Index action returning a View(), and my Index.cshtml

While debugging, I put a breakpoint on my controller but the execution never reaches it. Maybe I'm missing something about the routes.

Is there something else that i'm missing?

edit: here's my program.cs as requested

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: Can you post your Program.cs?

Comment: Simply create another project with default template and compare or create the whole structure with your empty created project.

Comment: @Nikki9696 i will edit into my question.

Comment: @Imran I created another project to guide me while creating the structure on my empty project, and at the moment I couldn't find what i'm missing.

Comment: According to me, no need to create empty project for learning. Just create default solution, get understanding of important files from there and kick start to development.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have this tree dictionaries

```
│   app.csproj
│   appsettings.Development.json
│   appsettings.json
│   Program.cs
│   Startup.cs
│
│
├───bin
│   └───Debug
│
├───Controllers
│       HomeController.cs
│
├───obj
│   │
│   └───Debug
│       
│
└───Views
    └───Home
            Index.cshtml
```

Comment: Except for the Views and Controllers, that structure was created by default.

Comment: @D.Fernandes, Can you provide us with Views and Controllers structure in your project for reference? Please make sure that the `Index.cshtml` view is in the `/Views/Home/` folder, and make sure that `HomeController` contains the `Index action` of `return View()`.

Comment: @YongqingYu my structure is the same as yours and I also created a mvc project to compare the structure. I tried changing the Index method to return the http status code 200 but wasn't successful either.

Comment: @D.Fernandes, Can you provide us with the log when you running the project?

Comment: @YongqingYu Sure, I ran the project with verbosity level set to Diagnostic. Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/HXYQ7GMh